# Table labeling and numbering

Tags: tables, numbering, labels

I have a table I had to split in to, so now one is table 6 and the other table 7. I would like them to be have the label 6.1 and 6.2 instead. Is there a way to do this.

Comment: Use the `subtable` environment  from `subcaption` for each of you split tables.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the details:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begin{table}[p]
\def\thetable{\arabic{table}.1}% local to this table
\caption{First part}\label{first}
\end{table}
%
\begin{table}[p]
\addtocounter{table}{-1}% global
\def\thetable{\arabic{table}.2}% local to this table
\caption{Second part}\label{second}
\end{table}
%
\begin{table}[p]
\caption{normal table}
\end{table}

\bigskip
See tables \ref{first} and \ref{second}.

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

you could add -1 to the table counter before starting the second part of your table.

I strongly voted against this technical solution, because it won't be clear for the reader, which table to consult.  Imagine: you've placed a label and use a ref, to point out to that **one** table, but the reader will find instead to tables with the same number.  Which one is the correct?

Hence the question: why did you divide your table into two pieces?

Is your table to long, to be presented on one physical page?

If so, you should probably check out packages, that will typeset tables across multiple pages, for example the [longtable package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) (amongst others!). It'll split the tables automatically for you, whenever the need should be.